# Convert map to the string array with separator

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, collections

How to convert such map:

```
val map = mapOf(
    "A" to "1",
    "B" to mapOf(
        "C" to "2"
    )
)
```

to the string array:

```
["A=1", "B.C=2"]
```

Comment: What types of values are expected? Only strings and maps?

Comment: Yes. Only strings and maps.

Comment: If there would be `D to 3` along with C, should the output be `["A=1", "B.C=2", "B.D=3"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:

```
fun toStringList(map: Map<*, *>): List<String> {
    val result = ArrayList<String>()

    fun processSubmap(submap: Map<*, *>, prefix: String = "") {
        submap.apply{} .forEach { (k,v) ->
            if(v is Map<*,*>) {
                processSubmap(
                    v,
                    if(prefix.isEmpty()) k.toString() else "$prefix.$k"
                )
            } else {
                val left = if(prefix.isEmpty()) k.toString() else "$prefix.$k"
                result.add("$left=$v")
            }
        }
    }

    processSubmap(map)
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with this:

```
    fun print(map: Map<*, *>): List<String> = map.map { (key, value) -> when (value) {
        is Map<*,*> -> "$key.${print(value).single()}"
        else ->  "$key=$value"
    } }
```

You haven't said what to do if the sub-map contains anything other than one entry, but you can adjust this code as needed.

Comment: Map values may contain strings and submaps.